# visual studio express 2012 for web - condition breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have visual studio 2012 for web EXPRESS - can I set in loop in debug mode breakpoint and Condition when application should stop? For example I have loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 6000; i++)
{
    //...........
}
```

I would like to see what is wrong when i = 3000, how can I do that?

**EDIT:**

**I don't have under breakpoint option 'Condition':**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set the breakpoint as normal (via right-click or F9) then right-click the red dot in the editor margin, click "Condition", and enter `i == 3000`.

**Edit**: It seems that VS Express 2012 for Web doesn't have this feature.

Comment: I checked on my Visual Studio. Desktop version has this options while web does not.

Comment: Remove a small bunch of useful features so the free version is mostly useful but has really irritating bits removed, nice up-sell =(